# Fixed-point subspace of $O(2)^-$, a subgroup of $O(3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, symmetric-groups, symmetry

$O(2)^-$ is generated by the $SO(2)$ of rotations about the $z$-axis and a reflection through a vertical plane.

The space $V_l$ is generated by spherial harmonics, i.e., Cartan decomposition
$$V_l=span\{Y_{l,m}\}_{m=-l}^{l}=H_0\oplus H_1 \oplus \cdots\oplus H_l\;(dim H_0=1,\;dim H_k=2 (k\geq 1))$$
where $ Y_{l,m}(\theta,\phi) = (-1)^m\sqrt{\frac{(2l+1)(l-m)!}{2(l+m)!}}
 \;P^m_l(\cos\theta) \frac{e^{im\phi}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} 
 (m=-l,\cdots,l)
$, 
the associated Legendre polynomial $P^m_l(z) = \frac1{2^ll!} (1-z^2)^{m/2}
 \frac{d^{l+m}}{dz^{l+m}}(z^2-1)^l $, and
 $\theta$ and $\phi$ represent colatitude and longitude, respectively. In particular, the colatitude $\theta$, or polar angle, ranges from $0$ at the North Pole, to $\pi/2$ at the Equator, to $\pi$ at the South Pole, and the longitude $\phi$, or azimuth, may assume all values with $0\leq\theta<2\pi$.

The monograph of Golubitsky-Stewart-Schaeffer(1988)[Vol.II, pp.126] says that the dimension of fixed-point subspace $Fix_{V_l}(O(2)^-)$ is $0$ as $l$ even and $1$ as $l$ odd, where $$Fix_{V_l}(O(2)^-)=\{v\in V_l| v(A^Tx)=v(x) \text{ for all } A\in O(2)^- \}.$$

**Problem**: I think that $Fix_{V_l}(SO(2))=\{ Y_{l,0}\}$, $ Y_{l,0}(\theta) = \sqrt{\frac{(2l+1)l!}{2l!}}
 \;P^0_l(\cos\theta) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} $.
Also, $ Y_{l,0}$ is independent of $\phi$ and is invariant under a reflection through a vertical plane.
Hence I think that the dimension of $Fix_{V_l}(O(2)^-)$ is also $1$ as $l$ even.

So I want to know why the dimension of $Fix_{V_l}(O(2)^-)$ is $0$ as $l$ even. Where is wrong  in my above analysis?